# How to join tables together based on subselects?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I'm stuck to figure out how to write a query. Basically I've three tables (Orders, Products, Orders_Products) which I want to join together and apply some filtering.

```
Orders table:
  ORDER_ID   CUSTOMER_ID
  1          1
  2          2

Products table:
  PRODUCT_ID   PRODUCT_NAME    PRODUCT_TITLE
  1            'P1'            'T1'
  2            'P1'            'T2'
  3            'P2'            'T3'
  4            'P2'            'T4'
  5            'P2'            'T5'
  6            'P3'            'T6'

Orders_Products table:
  ORDER_ID   PRODUCT_ID
  1          1
  1          3
  2          1
  2          3
  2          6
```

For example I want to get all Orders which consists (exactly) of the products P1/T1 and P2/T3. I tried something like this, but that doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Orders_Products ON Orders_Products.ORDER_ID = Orders.ORDER_ID
LEFT JOIN Products ON Orders_Products.PRODUCT_ID = Products.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Product WHERE PRODUCT_NAME = 'P1' AND PRODUCT_TITLE = 'T1')
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Product WHERE PRODUCT_NAME = 'P2' AND PRODUCT_TITLE = 'T3');
```

EDIT: To clarify what I really have to achieve. The user should be able to search for orders matching the given products. The user enters one or more product name / product title combinations and gets all the orders which have exactly this products associated. What I get (from a web application) are only the name/title combinations and I have to use those in a query to get the ORDER_ID.

Comment: What flavour SQL are you using? SQL Server (if so, which version)?

Comment: I'm using MySQL, but I wonder if something cannot be done using standard SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably cannot write simple queries in MySQL to achieve this. But ANSI SQL supports `table value constructor` which simplifies this type of query.

This basic query returns the full list of orders (5 rows):

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
JOIN Orders_Products ON Orders_Products.PRODUCT_ID = Products.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN Orders ON Orders_Products.ORDER_ID = Orders.ORDER_ID
```

This query with `table value constructor` returns the orders that you need:

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
JOIN Orders_Products ON Orders_Products.PRODUCT_ID = Products.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN Orders ON Orders_Products.ORDER_ID = Orders.ORDER_ID 
LEFT JOIN (VALUES('P1', 'T1'), ('P2', 'T3')) V(P_NAME, P_TITLE) ON PRODUCT_NAME = P_NAME AND PRODUCT_TITLE=P_TITLE
```

This query groups the above to returns the ORDER_ID where there is no order outside the required list (eliminating the orders that have rows containing null):

```
SELECT ORDER_ID FROM Products 
JOIN Orders_Products ON Orders_Products.PRODUCT_ID = Products.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN Orders ON Orders_Products.ORDER_ID = Orders.ORDER_ID 
LEFT JOIN (VALUES('P1', 'T1'), ('P2', 'T3')) V(P_NAME, P_TITLE) ON PRODUCT_NAME = P_NAME AND PRODUCT_TITLE=P_TITLE
GROUP BY ORDER_ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Among open source databases, [HSQLD](http://hsqldb.org)B is one that supports table value constructor and other user friendly features of ANSI SQL:2008

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats exactly what I'm looking for. But unfortunately MySQL doesn't support 'table value constructors'. But I can emulate it using `LEFT JOIN (SELECT v.PRODUCT_NAME, v.PRODUCT_TITLE FROM Products v WHERE (v.PRODUCT_NAME = 'P1' AND PRODUCT_TITLE = 'T1') OR (v.PRODUCT_NAME = 'P2' AND PRODUCT_TITLE = 'T3')) tmp ON PRODUCT_NAME=tmp.PRODUCT_NAME AND PRODUCT_TITLE=tmp.PRODUCT_TITLE`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT OrderID, COUNT(*) AS ProductsCount
FROM Orders_Products
WHERE (PRODUCT_ID = 1 OR PRODUCT_ID = 3)
GROUP BY OrderID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

EDIT: Please ignore the above statement. See if the following works.

```
SELECT OrderID, 
SUM(CASE PRODUCT_ID WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 3 END)
AS ProductsCount
FROM Orders_Products
GROUP BY OrderID
HAVING SUM(CASE PRODUCT_ID WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 3 END) = 2
```

I guess this should get you Orders which has **only** these 2 products.

Comment: Does it give orders that have *only* those two products? The OP is trying to match orders which `"consists (exactly) of"` the two products so, I'd read it that they don't want orders that happen to also include any other items.

Comment: @DMA57361: If I understand you right, OP needs records for ORDER_ID = 1. Please see the corrected statement above.

Comment: Bare in mind what I'm stating is my interpretation of the OP's needs :) - but I reckon your amended version would manage that.

Comment: I've clarified what I want to achieve. Is this possible with one of your two solutions?